# SQLite set records with matching checksums to same value if value is not set

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update, subquery

I have a table that contains images: ***imageArchive***

- Images in the table are not unique
- There is a ***checksum*** field that lets you know which images are identical
- The record also contains a ***userID***, but in many cases this field is NULL

How can I, if one record with a given checkSum has a userID, set all records with that checksum to the known userId?

I've gotten as far as:

```
select imageChksum from imageArchive 
where userId != "NULL"
group by imagechksum
```

which gives me the set of known checksums that have userIds

and:

```
select * from imageArchive 
where imagechksum in
(select imageChksum from imageArchive 
where userId != "NULL"
group by imagechksum)
```

which gives me a list of targets to set.  However I'm clueless as to how to set them all... probably simple? I'm pretty much self-taught in SQL and generally would do something like this in code but have a sense that I might be close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select imageChksum, max(userid) over(partition by imageChksum) as userid
from imageArchive
```

Note that if there are two different users assigned to the same checksum, the greatest id will be chosen.

If you wanted an `update` statement, I would recommend correlated subqueries:

```
update imageArchive
set userid = (select max(ia1.userid) from imageArchive ia1 where ia1.imageChksum = imageArchive.imageChksum)
where 
    userid is null 
    and exists (select 1 from imageArchive ia1 where ia1.imageChksum = imageArchive.imageChksum)
```

Comment: I very much like your strategy (to the degree I understand it) on the update... max value would always be acceptable since the checksum is null or discrete.  However, getting "near "ia": syntax error (Line 5)" currently.  Staring at it but still not grokking it..

Comment: @JcNolan: my bad. I fixed the query.

Comment: Thank you... that does indeed work.  In fact I found a "cheap" solution where I could do it with just hardcoded statements (I had a list of the checksums) and it generated the same answer - woo hoo!  Only trouble is my "cheap" solution ran in just a few seconds and yours took about 30 mins (on 3000 records).  I totally get they are doing very different things... but is the time just going to take that long?  Certainly can't use that in production... but it solved my immediate problem which was trying to rebuild some lost data.